# Variable set to t as setting to REQUIRE-MATCH

Tags: completion

How can I use a variable `mustmatch` set to `t` that is used as the setting for `REQUIRE-MATCH`?

```
(completing-read prompt 'read-file-name-internal pred mustmatch 
  insdef 'file-name-history default-filename)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question: "how can I use a variable `mustmatch` ...". The obvious answer is: the same way you use any other variable, but I suspect you'll find that as useful as I found your question to be understandable. Use it where and for what purpose? What are you trying to do? I would suggest that you spend some time putting yourself in the place of a potential respondent trying to figure out what you mean. Another suggestion: read [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) or a similar guide.

Comment: It is the argument slot in completing-read named `REQUIRE-MATCH`.  Instead of using `t` or `nil`, I want to use a variable `mustmatch` that evaluates to `t`.

Comment: Then just pass the variable as the argument.

Comment: Are there any rules upon whether one passes a variable name or a symbol?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way

```
  (let* ( (mustmatch t)
          (cseq '("bracemk" "extended" "expression" "mixed"
                  "hlsexp" "disable"))
          (csel  (completing-read "Flare_type: " cseq nil mustmatch
                    "mixed" 'flare-hist "extended")))
```

Comment: Why not pass in `t` directly? `(completing-read "Flare_type: " cseq nil t "mixed" 'flare-hist "extended")`

Comment: Because I want to see what it refers to.  There are quite a few parameters in `completing-read` and find it easy to read without having to look at the documentation,

Comment: FYI: You can also use a keyword arg `:mustmatch` (that evaluates to itself). It's almost the same as using `t` (or a variable bound to `t`).

Comment: Put the cursor on the name of the function and do `C-h f RET`. I do that all the time with lisp functions. I also do `M-x man` on commands, system calls and glibc functions for the same reason. The doc is accessible quickly and easily and I don't need to remember these details. OTOH, cluttering up the program by setting unnecessary variables is going to make your life difficult for as long as you maintain that program.